# 'Field userRepository in com.userproject.Service.UserService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This is User class, which serves as the Entity.

```
package com.userproject.Entities;

import jakarta.persistence.Column; 
import jakarta.persistence.Entity; 
import jakarta.persistence.Id; 
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity 
@Table(name = "userservice") 
public class User {

@Id
@Column(name="userID")
int userId;

@Column(name="username")
String username;

@Column(name="age")
int age;



public User(int userId, String username, int age) {
    super();
    this.userId = userId;
    this.username = username;
    this.age = age;
}

public User() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [userId=" + userId + ", username=" + username + ", age=" + age + "]";
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

}
```

This is my repository interface

```
package com.userproject.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.userproject.Entities.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

public User findById(int id);

}
```

This is my Service class

```
package com.userproject.Service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service; 
import com.userproject.Entities.User; 
import com.userproject.dao.UserRepository;

@Service 
public class UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public User addUser(User usr) {
    User savedUser = this.userRepository.save(usr);
    return savedUser;
}

public List<User> getAllInfo(){
    Iterable<User> allUsers = this.userRepository.findAll();
    return (List<User>)allUsers;
}

public User getUser(int usrId) {
    User usr = this.userRepository.findById(usrId);
    if (usr == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    return usr;
}

}
```

This is my Controller

```
package com.userproject.Controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus; 
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import com.userproject.Entities.User; 
import com.userproject.Service.UserService;

@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/user") 
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService service;


@PostMapping("/add")
public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody User u){
    try {
        User addUser = this.service.addUser(u);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(addUser);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<User> getUserById(@PathVariable("id") int userID){
    try {
        User u = this.service.getUser(userID);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(u);
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}

@GetMapping("/all")
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUsers(){
    try {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.service.getAllInfo());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}

}
```

This is my main application class

```
package com.userproject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication; 
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration; 
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableJpaRepositories("com.userproject.dao") 
@SpringBootApplication(exclude =  {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }) 
public class UserProjectApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 SpringApplication.run(UserProjectApplication.class, args);
    
}

}
```

This is application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.database=mysql 
spring.datasource.username=***** 
spring.datasource.password=***** 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://*******:3306/practice 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
spring.jooq.sql-dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

This is my project structure:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR10B.png)

When I try to run the application, I keep getting the following message: `

```
Description:

Field userRepository in com.userproject.Service.UserService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

If I remove the "exclude" parameter from @SpringBootApplication, it throws an error stating the datasource cannot be configured as the url is missing.
If I remove the @EnableJpaRepositories, it throws an error stating my userRepository field in Service class cannot be configured.

From what I understand, this whole problem arises from me trying to autowire the userRepository field (which is actually an interface) in the Service class. However, SpringBoot shall be able to do that with the help of proxy classes.

Please provide me with a solution to this.

Comment: How do you think JPA will connect to a database... Through a `DataSource` for which you disabled the configuration through excluding the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`. Also the `@EnableJpaRepositories` can be removed as well.

Comment: If you get an error on the datasource config, fix the config, don't exclude the auto configuration. Excluding that isn't the solution, the solution is to provide the proper information to configure the datasource. Looking at what you posted you indeed didn't specify the URL as that isn't on a dedicated line but rather part of the password.

Comment: Can you please pom.xml file as well